# SELECT keyword in wrong position

Tags: mysql, sql

I've recently started writing MySQL, but I've encoutered a problem which seems childish, but I can't solve it. I've created a fuction that simply adds to VARCHARS toghether and now I'm trying to execute the function with all values from two columns. The problem is that the keyword SELECT is in the wrong position though it doesn't look so...

```
SELECT create_full_name_2(SELECT name FROM person, SELECT surname FROM person);
```

The first select throws an error.

Answer (score 4):

It should be rather:

```
SELECT create_full_name_2(name, surname)
FROM person;
```